# Add custom repository to composer

Tags: php, composer-php

I have a gitlab repo: http://gitlabPerso/gitlab/PROJECTS/my-project.git

And I would like to add it to my current composer.json project.

However it keeps saying me:

> - The requested package project/MyProjectBundle could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.

This is what I tried:

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "package",
        "package": {
            "name": "project/MyProjectBundle",
            "version": "dev-master",
            "type": "package",
            "source": {
                "url": "http://gitlabPerso/gitlab/PROJECTS/my-project.git",
                "type": "git",
                "reference": "master"
            }
        }
    }
],
"require": {
    "project/MyProjectBundle": "*"
 }
```

And the composer.json in this project looks like this:

```
{
"name" : "project/MyProjectBundle",
"description" : "some description", 
"type" : "symfony-bundle",
"license": [
    "MIT"
],
"require" : {
        "php" : ">=5.3.0"
},
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"prefer-stable": true
}
```

I tried many other solutions I found on the net, I RTFM, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Easiest way would be to put it on `packagist.org`. Or read [the manual](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#loading-a-package-from-a-vcs-repository) again

Comment: check the url and repo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally find this solution:

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "git",
        "url": "repogit.git"
    }
],
```

Comment: Good for you, but Edi wrote you the solution in March 16th.

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "http://gitlabPerso/gitlab/PROJECTS/my-project.git"
    }
],
"require": {
    "project/MyProjectBundle": "*"
}
```